# Isolate all Substrings of a given structure in Python

Tags: python, regex, substring

I'm currently trying to write a program that goes through a chat log generated by a site for online TTRPG playing. Currently, my output is as follows:

> rolling 7d10(1+4+5+3+8+8+3)=32rolling 7d10(6+8+3+9+7+10+8)=51rolling 7d10(7+7+6+6+8+3+5)=42rolling 4d10(3+3+3+4)=13rolling 7d10(5+5+10+7+4+9+10)=50rolling 1d10 + 8(10)+8=18

I want every substring of this to be given as an independent string. In this case, a "substring" would be anything following the structure

> rolling xdy(1+2+3...+z)=a

I'm fairly certain that I'd need a Regex for this, but what this would look like (I'm not that good with Regex I'll admit) is beyond me.

Answer (score 2):

From the structure you shared `rolling xdy(1+2+3...+z)=a` replace everyletter representing a number by `\d+` (one or more digit) and with some ajustments you'll obtain

```
rolling \d+d\d+\((?:\d+\+)*\d+\)=\d+
```

[<kbd>Regex demo</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/jzcKT0/1)

---

```
import re

text = "rolling 7d10(1+4+5+3+8+8+3)=32rolling 7d10(6+8+3+9+7+10+8)=51rolling " \
       "7d10(7+7+6+6+8+3+5)=42rolling 4d10(3+3+3+4)=13rolling " \
       "7d10(5+5+10+7+4+9+10)=50rolling 1d10 + 8(10)+8=18"
results = re.findall(r"rolling \d+d\d+\((?:\d+\+)*\d+\)=\d+", text)
print(results)
```

```
['rolling 7d10(1+4+5+3+8+8+3)=32', 'rolling 7d10(6+8+3+9+7+10+8)=51', 
 'rolling 7d10(7+7+6+6+8+3+5)=42', 'rolling 4d10(3+3+3+4)=13', 
 'rolling 7d10(5+5+10+7+4+9+10)=50']
```

Note that the last one isn't valid as there is numbers and `+` sign outside the parenthesis

Answer (score 2):

You can solve your task without regex like this

```
data = "rolling 7d10(1+4+5+3+8+8+3)=32rolling 7d10(6+8+3+9+7+10+8)=51rolling 7d10(7+7+6+6+8+3+5)=42rolling 4d10(3+3+3+4)=13rolling 7d10(5+5+10+7+4+9+10)=50rolling 1d10 + 8(10)+8=18"

parts = data.split("rolling")[1:]
print(parts)
# [' 7d10(1+4+5+3+8+8+3)=32', ' 7d10(6+8+3+9+7+10+8)=51', ' 7d10(7+7+6+6+8+3+5)=42', ' 4d10(3+3+3+4)=13', ' 7d10(5+5+10+7+4+9+10)=50', ' 1d10 + 8(10)+8=18']
```

If you need, you can attach string `rolling` back to parts

```
parts = ["rolling" + p for p in parts]
print(parts)
# ['rolling 7d10(1+4+5+3+8+8+3)=32', 'rolling 7d10(6+8+3+9+7+10+8)=51', 'rolling 7d10(7+7+6+6+8+3+5)=42', 'rolling 4d10(3+3+3+4)=13', 'rolling 7d10(5+5+10+7+4+9+10)=50', 'rolling 1d10 + 8(10)+8=18']
```

Answer (score 0):

It's much better to have the logger put a line terminator after each entry, but this will give you an array of rolls from your luxuriant purse of d10s.

```
import re

log_contents = 'rolling 7d10(1+4+5+3+8+8+3)=32rolling 7d10(6+8+3+9+7+10+8)=51rolling 7d10(7+7+6+6+8+3+5)=42rolling 4d10(3+3+3+4)=13rolling 7d10(5+5+10+7+4+9+10)=50rolling 1d10 + 8(10)+8=18'

pattern = re.compile('(=[0-9]*)')
rolls = pattern.sub(r'\1\n', log_contents).rstrip().split('\n')
```